# Nth day of every Mth month in Rust

Tags: time, rust, calendar

I've been trying to find a crate to deal with complex time sequences.
Using the excellent [kronos](https://crates.io/crates/kronos) crate, I can create `TimeSequence`s like the "10th day of every month" or "the first Monday of every year" with `NthOf` and `Grains()`.

```rust
// 10th day of every month
tenth_day = NthOf(10, Grains(Grain::Day), Grains(Grain::Month));

// 1st Monday of every year
first_monday = Nth(1, Weekday(1), Grains(Grain::Year));
```

But I want to do this for more complex `TimeSequence`s, like "the 27th day of every other month".
There are the `Grain::Quarter` and `Grain::Half` enum variants for every 3 and 6 months, respectively, but these are hard-coded and do not generalize to months that don't divide the year evenly, like every 5 months.

Is there a way I can get these more complex `TimeSequence`s with `kronos`? Or is there another crate I could use for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [discussing with `kronos`' maintainer](https://github.com/rodolf0/tox/pull/8#issuecomment-691603697), using the [`step_by`](https://docs.rs/kronos/0.1.4/kronos/fn.step_by.html) function or `step_by` method can make this work.

Here is an example with the `step_by` method on a `Grains` object.

```rust
use chrono::Datelike;

let mut every_3months_from_next_march_iter = Grains(Grain::Month)
    .future(&t0_april)
    .skip_while(|r| r.start.date().month() != 3)
    .step_by(3);
assert_eq!(
    every_3months_from_next_march_iter.next().unwrap(),
    Range{
        start: dt(2019, 3, 1),
        end: dt(2019, 4, 1), grain: Grain::Month
    }
);
```

And here is an example with the `step_by` function.

```rust
use kronos::{step_by, Grains, Grain, NthOf};

let third_day_every_5_months = NthOf(
    3,
    Grains(Grain::Day),
    step_by(Grains(Grain::Month), 5)
);
```